# Need help constructing a grammar?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

```
L = ((a^n)(b^n+m)(a^m)) | n, m = 0, 1, 2...)
```

I'm new to context free grammar and know the basics, but I've been struggling with this for a while.

For starters, I dont know what this part of the code means:

```
| n, m = 0, 1, 2...)
```

And secondly, how is it possible to have the same variable with different exponents? I feel like I'm not getting the full concept.

Edit: I also need to be able to construct the rules to construct this grammar.

Edit: added tag

Comment: Is that the entire problem description / is this homework?

Comment: yeah, I just added the tag. The question was asking To construct a grammar that generates the following language. I also added some stuff I didn't understand which Michael helped out with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, describe the language in words. This language has a particularly neat description: it is the language of all strings beginning with a's, followed by b's, followed by a's, where the number of b's is equal to the total number of a's (on both sides).

Next, we are going to try to come up with a rule to take strings in the language and produce new strings. Given a string, you can get the next longest string by adding an a to the front and a b in the middle, or an a to the back and a b in the middle. The empty string is in this language (n = m = 0), too, so this can serve as the base for the induction. If we look at this a little closer, we can get an even better rule: we can split any string a^n b^n+m a^m into two strings (a^n b^n)(a^m b^m). Since concatenation is easy to do with grammars and a^k b^k is easy to do with grammars, that's all there is to it.

I get the rules...

```
  S := LR
  L := empty | aLb
  R := empty | bRa
```

To get e.g. aabbba,...

```
  S := LR := aLbR := aaLbbR := aabbR := aabbbRa := aabbba
```

If this is homework, tagging it as such would be good. If this is self study, hopefully you'll take away the following tricks: describe the language in English; try to identify easy base cases; try to identify rules for forming more complicated strings (i.e. longer strings) from strings already in the language; reformulate your rules and/or notice tricks so that you can state the rules in terms of things that are easy in grammars; write the grammar and check it on a few strings.

What is easy to do in a grammar? Union of languages, concatenation of languages, even matching of pairs of symbols (e.g. a^k b^k), palindromes, etc.

Comment: Man, this was phenomenal. Now with grammar, is it correct if no matter what order you apply the rules it comes out to the answer at some point? Even if you reused the a rule multiple times?

Comment: You may apply any rule, so long as the string you're constructing has as a substring something on the left hand side of a production/rule; you may use any rule any number of times, as you are able. Classes of grammars differ only in terms of the restrictions placed on productions: characteristics of the LHS and RHS, and the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1):

That is just mathematical notation for a restriction on the values of n and m. It means that for a string consisting of the form `(a^n)*(b^n+m)*a^m`, "n" and "m" are two separate values (although they may be equal), and the 0, 1, 2... just means they are any integer value greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Could you explain how to go about constructing the rules for the grammar?

Comment: Sorry, no. I can't quite figure out what your language specification means, because I am used to a different format.

Comment: Thanks anyways, your answer did move me forward!